# What is the song of this guitar intro?

Tags: identify-this-song, guitar

I'm looking to remember the song that is used in the opening of this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oZ83TgFvUFM). I remember it being very famous (and probably from the 80's or 90's), but i can't remember!

(I've got a impression it was b52 or oingo boingo, but couldn't find it in their songs)

Comment: You got a timestamp? All I see is some guy yelling in 'foreign'

Comment: @Tetsujin, it might be the short guitar riff on the very beginning of the video.

Comment: ahh - it was over before I even got to my volume dial ;-) It's Billy Idol, Rebel Yell

Comment: White Wedding, not Rebel Yell

Comment: Sorry, @HenriAugusto - my initial comment was erroneous. I missed the first couple of seconds before I'd turned up my volume & didn't realise there was only about 1 second of the riff - good job I recognised it immediately, though it took me a couple of minutes to figure out which Billy Idol song it was.

Comment: @Tetsujin  Portuguese is the 'foreign.'

Comment: @M.Mat - yeah, I wasn't sure. Didn't think it was Spanish, of which I speak about 6 words, wasn't certain enough of it being Portuguese. I really would have removed my less-than-patient comment had it not been part of the flow of later comments - so, red-faced, I left it there ;-) My own *stoopid* fault for not having the speakers up when the vid started.

Comment: Portuguese has the distinction of sounding like Spanish and Russian (or something Slavic). People often don't recognize the spoken language.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's Billy Idol - White Wedding (1982)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AAZQaYKZMTI

Wikipedia: [White Wedding (song)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_Wedding_(song))

Comment: Thanks! 

I did too thought for a second about Billy Idol haha and i've tried Rebell Yell and Dancing With Myself but gave up on him after that. Because i've thought those were his only two songs i knew. Just happens i forgot i've used to listen White Wedding as i child! That intro sounded so familiar. Now thats a memorable intro!

Comment: Absolutely. I recognised it immediately - but jumped to the wrong initial conclusion. As soon as I heard the rebel yell intro then I knew it was White wedding instead. Finding the videos on YouTube actually took longer than the mental process. That is one great intro. Check out 'Eyes Without a Face' for the last great song he did in that series. Again, some lovely guitar work & I think his best song overall.